# Colaboración para averiguar escritura

Tags: escritura

Estoy realizando el árbol genealógico de mi familia y es una locura en algunos casos descifrar lo que pone.
En este caso son 2 nombres, el primero es un nombre de hombre con apellido Hidalgo, y el otro es nombre de mujer con apellido Viejo.
¿Me podeis ayudar?

Gracias!
[image]

Comment: Este no es el lugar para esto. Por favor.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about Spanish.

Comment: Lo siento, vi otra pregunta similar y nadie le dijo nada al respecto sobre que no era el lugar, pense que podía publicarlo aquí.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Que es nieto por parte paterna de Rufino Hidalgo

> y de Basilisa Viejo

<sub>*[Nombre femenino Basilisa](https://www.todopapas.com/nombres/nombres-de-nina/basilisa#:%7E:text=Significado%20de%20Basilisa,Variante%20de%20Basilia.)*</sub>

Comment: The initial letters look similar to me so I would incline to Beltran.

Answer (score 0):

Yo leo "Beltrán Hidalgo y Basilia Viejo".

Si bien en un principio pensé en "Bufinio", un nombre antiguo y no muy extendido, desde otro punto de vista el nombre se me antoja "Beltrán", pues aparece una superposición de letras, "l y t", siendo ese el motivo por el que se puede observar la línea horizontal de la "t", como si al redactar se hubieran equivocado y hubiera querido arreglar el error escribiendo encima juntándose con una "r" ligada acabando en una marca que por su inclinación me atrevería a decir que es un acento. Por tanto para mi "Beltrán" hasta ahora es la mejor opción.

En cuanto a "Basilia", también podría ser "Basilisa" como han comentado en otra respuesta, la forma simplemente me recuerda a las antiguas caligrafías entrelazadas y a los picos que se producían confundiéndolos a veces con una "i" sin punto.

P.D. Lorena bienvenida a la comunidad.